# AngleSharp Css Query For Element Style Using Path

Tags: anglesharp

Given only a css stylesheet, is it possible to parse and query the stylesheet using some sort of a path query to retrieve a computed style similar to what is returned from `IElement.ComputeCurrentStyle()`?

```cs
var css = @"
<style>
   table { font-family:foobar }
   td { font-weight:bold }
</style>
";

var config = Configuration.Default.WithDefaultLoader().WithCss();
var context = BrowsingContext.New(config);
IDocument document = await context.OpenAsync(req => req.Content(css));
ICssStyleSheet sheet = document.GetStyleSheets().OfType<ICssStyleSheet>().First()
```

Is it possible to do something like `sheet.GetComputedStyle("body>table>tbody>tr>td")` to retrieve a `ICssStyleDeclaration`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got a response to this on the github project issue tracker
https://github.com/AngleSharp/AngleSharp.Css/issues/64

> Well to get a computed style you need to have a connection to the DOM. After all, things like selectors can only be computed in context of an available DOM structure.
> I guess what you are after is to "fake" the DOM, i.e., if you see some selector (like body>table>tbody>tr>td) create the minimal DOM to be able to get an element that satisfies the selector. Then use this element to get the computed style, right?
> Out of the box this is not possible, but I think it should be doable to write this.